# Roth IRA withdrawal taxes for nonresident aliens after age 59 1/2?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, non-resident, withdrawal

I am a non-resident alien living in the US now, and I need to ask if I have to pay any IRS any taxes after the age of 59 1/2 on any gains or earnings from a Roth IRA withdrawals?

I know that US residents and green card holders do not pay any taxes on Roth IRA withdrawals after age of 59 1/2. Is that any different for non-resident aliens?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're living in the US now, how are you a non-resident alien?

Comment: @DJohnM : [It's perfectly possible to live in the US and be a nonresident alien from an IRS perspective.](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Determining-Alien-Tax-Status)  Basically, if you've not been in the US for a significant time period in the current (and previous) tax year(s), but are currently living in hte US, you can be nonresident for tax purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not different. However, you're probably resident (for tax purposes) of your home country, and you'll need to check the rules there. It can definitely be considered taxable retirement income (with the basis of the original contribution).

Comment: I am concerned about IRS and not taxes at my home country. So I take it that no withholding will be made on any Roth IRA withdrawals after age of 59.5. I appreciate it if you can confirm! Many thanks!!!

Comment: @littleadv - is there also a 5 year rule or is that for conversions, not regular deposits?

Comment: @Mariam I have no idea about withholding. You asked about taxes. Your immigration or tax residency status has no bearing on the taxability of the withdrawing in the US. That said, Joe mentioned 5 years rule for conversions - this also still applies in your case. Bottom line - the rules don't change because of the change of your immigration status or tax residency.

Comment: For non-resident aliens, from what I read, if you do any withdrawals that are taxable, the payer has to do withholding of 30% unless the country has a tax agreement with the US. A special tax form has to be filled out W-9 (I think) by non-resident alien.

Comment: @Mariam yeah, but then you file a tax return and claim refund of all that was in excess to what you were supposed to pay.